Javascript range startContainer "wrong" in Safari
I have very simple test setup to demonstrate:


window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", (event) => {
    let selection = document.getSelection();
    let range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    console.log(range.startContainer);
  });
});
<p>startbuffer<span>test</span>endbuffer</p>



CodePen
If you select "endbuffer" the startContainer property of range is the span that surrounds test, in Firefox as expected the startContainer is text node endbuffer.
I need to consistently know the start container across browsers to be able to perform actions on the node that has been selected.
I can't fathom the logic in Safari, how can a node that is not part of the selection in anyway be the startContainer?


I have tested your code in safari and I receive two text containers, even if I select all the text in the span. Cannot replicate atm?

the endContainer is correct but startContainer is not for me.

I am getting either the startBuffer as text or the test as text for the startContainer. Could you do two things: could you remove the DOMContentLoaded (it will be by the time you click) and add selection && seletion.getRangeAt(0) and range && range.startContainer - this will stop a lot of errors from surrounding your logs. Perhaps also change it to a selectionchange event, as clicking and not selecting will give you a bunch of errors right here.

As I say select "endbuffer"

Still not able to replicate.

I have added a screenshot to avoid doubters trying to close this question, maybe the Safari version is a factor.

Your screenshot doesn't show that, It shows both containers as text nodes. Although the endOffset and startOffset don't seem to make a lick of sense looking at your selection, but that might have to do with the order of events. Again, I told you to rewrite it with selectionchange events to ensure that you are only logging when the selection is changed, and not a split second before, when the selection is maybe not yet correct? I have not seen safari have this problem, and I'm in the process of building a WYSIWYG editor. So... cannot replicate. You don't even seem to be able too.

I have changed the codepen to selectionchnage it makes no difference. The startContainer property should not be the "test" textNode, in Firefox it is correctly the "endbuffer" textNode, I think what I have posted is pretty clear.

I just tested it and it works fine: it says that the startContainer starts at test, but at offset 4 - which is exactly the amount of letters. The difference here is that it aligned the selection anchor to the end of the previous node, which is a decision more than a bug or an error. Even in your example screenshot it is perfectly valid. You could just check that if it has selectedno contents, and move the startContainer over to the next text element (whose order you could get with a TreeWalker). Text selection is complex, but in this case valid, no issues here.

Considering the range does not start in "test" then you may call it a decision if you want but it is a ridiculous nonsensical decision, Firefox reports the start container in a sensible logical way,  that you would expect. The fact this is solvable with a tonne of hacky code does not make your case for it being correct, merely that it isn't beyond repair. In my opinion it is most definitely a bug.
